# How to swap 2 section with vuedraggable

Tags: vue.js, sortablejs, vuedraggable

Hi i'm able to swap or order within a section very easily

But i'm failing to swap between 2 sections i,e from `leftSection` to `rightSection` as shown in image

[image]

Here is full code

https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-almeida-mbw2m?file=/src/App.vue

within `leftSection` i'm doing like this

```
      leftSection: [
        { Name: "L - A", order: 1 },
        { Name: "L - B", order: 2 },
        { Name: "L - C", order: 3 },
      ]

  <draggable
          v-model="leftSection"
          group="section"
          @start="drag = true"
          @end="drag = false"
        >
          <div v-for="section in leftSection" :key="section.Name" class="card">
            {{ section.Name }}
          </div>
    </draggable>
```

in similar way i'm doing for within `rightSection`  but don't know how to swap between 2 sections.

please help me thanks in advance..!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a single object and dynamically output it to a component
It might look something like this:

```
    <div class="section-wrapper">
      <draggable v-model="sections" group="sections">
        <div
         v-for="(item, index) of sections"
         :key="index"
         class="section-column"
        >
          <draggable
            v-model="sections[index].fields"
            group="{name: 'fields-' + index}"
          >
            <div
              v-for="(section, index) in item.fields"
              :key="index"
              class="card"
            >
              {{ section.Name }}
            </div>
          </draggable>
        </div>
      </draggable>
    </div>
<div class="display-section">
  <div v-for="left in sections[0].fields" :key="left.Name">
    {{ left.Name }}
  </div>
  <hr />
  <div v-for="right in sections[1].fields" :key="right.Name">
    {{ right.Name }}
  </div>
</div>

...
      sections: [
    {
      fields: [
        { Name: "L - A", order: 1 },
        { Name: "L - B", order: 2 },
        { Name: "L - C", order: 3 },
      ],
      order: 1,
    },
    {
      fields: [
        { Name: "R - A", order: 1 },
        { Name: "R - B", order: 2 },
      ],
      order: 2,
    },
  ],
  ...
```

Code template: [sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-wildflower-zhlzy?file=/src/App.vue:1052-1431)

However, one point should be taken into account. Since both columns are wrapped in a common draggable, elements can be moved between columns.

Comment: @AndreiPetrol, 1 tip i would like to get from you , if i don't want items from  ` 1red box` to be moved to `another red box`.

Comment: as shown in this image https://ibb.co/5R5xsqW

Comment: @EaBengaluru
remove group attribute:      group="{name: 'fields-' + index}"

Comment: @AndreiPetrol, please check this very interesting and challenging question of mine  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71736366/how-to-scroll-while-selecting-items-with-mouse-in-vue  and please help me