# Why nested array dynamic update is not working in my case

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

Hi i have a problem with nested array dynamic update as shown in below image

[image]

Here is a steps to re-produce the problem

1. click on `Add Likes` button it will add likes for eg `New Apple`
2. my default like is `Mango`
3. click on `Add about` button it will add next row (Mango is not appeared) click on `Add Likes` to see the problem.

For reducing code readability i have put helper function into a mixin file called `mixin.js`

**Expectation:**  i can add any number of `Add about` and `Add Likes`(with default value `Mango`)

**Here is my code:**   https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-hawking-di4d3?file=/src/App.vue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't need a nested array for the tags property.
Use:

```
getLikesTemplate() {
  let year = this.year;
  let template = {
    id: this.getUniqueId(),
    like: `I'm ${year} Old and like things like`,
    tags: [this.getTagsTemplate("Mango")]          //nesting removed
  };
  this.year++;
  return template;
}
```

Secondly, in JS objects are passed by reference, so you can do this:

method:

```
addLikes(like) {                                   //removed the extra code
  like.tags.push(this.getTagsTemplate("New Apple"));
},
```

template:

```
... 
<div style="text-align: left; display: flex">
  <div>                               //nesting removed
    <div class="tags" v-for="tag in like.tags" :key="tag.id">    
      {{ tag.name }}
    </div>
  </div>                              //passing the reference to the object
  <button style="margin-left: 20px" @click="addLikes(like)">
    Add Likes
  </button>
</div>
```

[Result img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lusB.png)

Comment: ..@Andrei Petrol, for each `Add about` will have its own tags i,e `Add Likes` so I have given like that.

Comment: Here is you corrected code: https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-nested-array-forked-y0mrd

Comment: @EaBengaluru That's right. You have tags already created for each "Add about". Therefore, nesting is not necessary. Link to the sandbox above

Comment: @AndreiPetrol  please check this question of mine still i'm looking for an answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70810699/how-to-swap-2-section-with-vuedraggable